# Old Hard Drive on new XBox

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

My old XBox RRoD'd for the 2nd time. No more repairing it, instead I got a new XBox 360 4GB.  I ordered a drive enclosure for my old XBox's 120GB hard drive to fit the form-factor of the new XBox however it hasn't arrived yet.

My question: I want to start playing the new XBox, I realize I won't have my profile, namely saved games (when is all that stuff gonna move to this cloud I've been hearing so much about?).  I just want to make sure before I go through the setup process that once I've setup my new XBox, I'll have the chance to import my profile from the old HDD once it's installed?

Secondary question: do I have the choice to move the profile info (saved games, etc...) to the 4GB inside the new XBox (which I'm presuming is SSD) or should I leave it on the HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that on the 360, saved games and Xbox Live profiles are ultimately stored in different "places". While you can keep both on a hard drive (or on a memory unit or flash drive if the saved games are small enough), saved games are only kept locally, while your Xbox Live profile is tracked on Microsoft's servers.

If you're talking about an Xbox Live profile, then it will "move" the first time you recover it - once you recover it from Microsoft's servers, that becomes your up-to-date profile, so you won't need to copy it from your hard drive. Your saved games won't be accessible until you get that enclosure so you can connect your old hard drive.

**Local** profiles, ones not associated with an Xbox Live account, are only stored locally, so if that's what you have, then you'll need to wait for the enclosure to arrive.

Once the hard drive is connected to your new 360, you can move whatever saved files will fit to the internal flash drive. (If you go to My Xbox, System Settings on the far right, and choose Memory, it'll show up as Memory Unit (3.x GB free), and you can copy files from your hard drive to it and vice versa.) I don't personally believe there's a difference between storing your profile on the internal drive and storing it on the hard drive. However, if you find yourself playing away from home on occasion, you may be better off picking up a small USB flash drive (up to 16 GB), formatting it for the 360, and storing your profile on that. You can simply pull the USB drive and take it to your friend's house without needing to recover your profile at either place.

Comment: I guess the disadvantage for me storing stuff on the 4GB internal is if something ever happened to the XBox (i.e. another RRoD).  That info might be lost forever.  I like the thought of storing stuff on a thumbdrive, but at the same time I don't trust thumbdrives as far as life expectancy goes.  For backup though, a brilliant idea.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ThaDon, happy to help. Yeah, I don't store anything more than my profile on a thumb drive ... I can always recover it if something happens, but would prefer not to risk saves. Good point about the possibility of losing access to the internal drive.

Comment: Bought a drive enclosure online (only $5), worked like a charm.  Only problem I had is my Burnout 3 (an XBox classic game) wouldn't allow me to load my saved games, it deemed the savegame profile I had created ingame "unusable".  However, Portal 2 was fine!  So probably just a problem with XBox classic games, no biggie for me.

Comment: @ThaDon, glad to hear it works for 360 games ... if the Xbox games are a problem, feel free to ask another question!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to move your profile over before removing the HDD from the old enclosure.  This is most easily done with the [XBox 360 Transfer Cable](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/Transfer).  Otherwise, old product keys (for DLC, XBLA purchases, etc) might not work properly with the new 360.

As for your second question, I would imagine you could put anything on the internal storage that you wanted, as long as it fits.